# Detect values enclosed between matrices and apply correction

Tags: matlab, matrix

Firstly, the title is probably not clear enough, sorry for that (can't decide what's a better title without using explanation). Let me explain better in words.

Let's say I have a matrix

```
A=[
0 0 0 0 0 -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 0 -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 ]
```

What I would like to this is detects the boundary between `0` and any values on per row and segment it by the enclosure. For row #1, I have `(0 -1`, `1 0)`, `(0 1`, `-1 0)`, thus using this information I would like to correct all the values on enclosed inside that boundary to positive or negative values depending on what it begins with and ends with. For example, the first row would become somehting like:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Any ideas that I can efficiently performs this because the matrix I'll be dealing with is of very large. Thanks you in advance!

**EDIT**

The enclosed values are not necessary 1. It can be any value ranges `[-1 1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
% example matrix:
A=[
0 0 0 0 0 0.5 0.9 -1 0.1 0.3 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0.9 -1 0.1 0.3 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 0;
0 0 0 0 0  0.1 0.3 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 0 -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 ];

[r,c]=find(A);
ind=sortrows([r c]);
steps=find(diff(ind(:,2))~=1);
steps=[[1; steps+1],[steps ;size(ind,1)]];
for k=1:size(steps,1)
  A(ind(steps(k,1),1),ind(steps(k,1),2):ind(steps(k,2),2))=A(ind(steps(k,1),1),ind(steps(k,1),2))
end

% result matrix:
A=
0   0   0   0   0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0   0   0   0   0   0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9 0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0   0   0   0   0   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  0   0   0   0   0
```

**EDIT**

I came with a vectorized solution, thanks to the new `repelem`. Now it works with continuous indexing in the matix `A`, and not with row and column, so I transposed `A` so that the interesting sequences through the matrix will have continuous indices:

```
A=A.';
B=find(A);
steps=diff([0;find(diff(B)>1) ;length(B)]);
vals=A(B([0 ;find(diff(B)>1)]+1));
A(A~=0)=repelem(vals,steps);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What if my value is not `1`, it can be any values between `[0 1]`. Any tip on this?

Comment: But the values are similar for each inner sequence, like in the question? I suggest you edit the question with all the information about the data

Comment: Nope, they're not. It can be `[0 0 0 0 -0.1 -0.3 -1 0.3 0.5 0.7 0 0 0]` something like that.

Comment: Ok, I see my edited answer. For that one, I doubt if there is a vectorized solution

Comment: I was gonna ask that. By the way, is it possible to keep the values of enclosed

Comment: Yes, use the left side of the assignment line (before the equal sign) that inside the loop. Before the assignment is performed, it contains these values.

Comment: Glad to help. If you, or someone, want, I added a vectorized solution.

Comment: Hey Adiel, can I ask you one more question? Using the vectorized method, it is possible for me to add tolerance before it assume the matrix is a enclosed one? For example, `[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 ]`, the actual matrix is enclosed within `[1 0 0 0 0 0 -1]`, so the correction would be `[0 0 0  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]`. For that, it means I'll have a tolerance of 1-5 before it found another boundary, which is the `-1`. I'm trying to figuring this out but I'm stuck :( Thanks once again.